# Is it Possible to change Worksheet names when useing ParseExcel?

Tags: perl, perl-module

Wrote a Perl script to parse an existing Excel workbook using [Spreadsheet::ParseExcel](http://p3rl.org/Spreadsheet%3a%3aParseExcel) (as a template), and create new file while adding updated data from our DB.

Is there a way to update the name of the individual worksheets prior to running the SaveAs function? I'd like to rename them to a customer number instead of the default Sheet1, Sheet2, etc. I did read the PerlDoc's and did see there is a `get_name()` option, but nothing to change and re-save.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Are you talking about creating a new workbook using [Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](https://metacpan.org/module/Spreadsheet::WriteExcel)?

Comment: No, only using data from an existing workbook, then making changes to certain cells, and saving as a different file. In this particular case, I'm not creating any new worksheets, just editing existing. Since the main file is a template, I want to save the worksheets used (there's 30 of them) by a customer number pertaining to the new data that is on each updated worksheet. I've been able to do all of this so far with using only Spreadsheet::ParseExcel.

Comment: I've adjusted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [SpreadSheet::WriteExcel](https://metacpan.org/module/Spreadsheet%3a%3aWriteExcel) you can specify the name of the worksheet as the method `add_worksheet`'s first param. This is what the [doc](https://metacpan.org/module/Spreadsheet%3a%3aWriteExcel#add_worksheet-sheetname-utf_16_be-) says:

```
$worksheet1 = $workbook->add_worksheet();           # Sheet1
$worksheet2 = $workbook->add_worksheet('Foglio2');  # Foglio2
$worksheet3 = $workbook->add_worksheet('Data');     # Data
$worksheet4 = $workbook->add_worksheet();           # Sheet4
```

So what you'd want to do is probably something like this:

```
while (my $res = $dbh->fetchrow_hashref) {
  my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet($res->{'customerName'});
  # do stuff with that sheet
}
```

---

**Update**:
Since you're only using Spreadsheet::ParseExcel here's another idea. There's no setter method for the name, so let's take a deeper look to find a workaround.

The [code of Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Worksheet](https://metacpan.org/source/JMCNAMARA/Spreadsheet-ParseExcel-0.59/lib/Spreadsheet/ParseExcel/Worksheet.pm) shows us how the name of a workbook-object is stored:

```
###############################################################################
#
# get_name()
#
# Returns the name of the worksheet.
#
sub get_name {

    my $self = shift;

    return $self->{Name};
}
```

You can just access the key *Name* directly via the worksheet-object.

```
$worksheet->{'Name'} = $res->{'customerName'};
```

**Disclaimer:** You should never meddle with internal values of objects, especially if you do not have control over their source. The internal structure may change in a future release, thus breaking your code!

Comment: Of course you could also monkeypatch your own setter-method into it, but that would still be dependent on the place of where the name is stored not changing.